# Filtering the data in power BI

Tags: filter, powerbi-desktop, datamodel

IM LEARNING NEWLY
im trying to filter the data of movies based on its genre as "Drama" using below query in **power bi** table view

```
**Justdramamovies = FILTER(IMDB_10000,IMDB_10000[genre]="Drama") **
```

but below error is encountered

> The expression refers to multiple columns. Multiple columns cannot be converted to a scalar value.

its not workibg why?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the FILTER() function in dax code. This function returns a table with the filtered rows base on the second parameter. This function has 2 parameters, the first one is the table, the second is the filter.

You could read the detail of this function at the following link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/filter-function-dax